# How to include an array of Parcelable objects with a savedInstanceStateBundle

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android app and trying to save data when the screen rotates.  I have this data in a array called mCheatedResults.  This is an array of custom objects that pair boolean data and an int.  My code for creating the class for the custom object is this:

```
    private class Pair implements Parcelable{
    private int mIndex;
    private boolean mCheated;

    public Pair(int mIndex, boolean mCheated){
        this.mIndex=mIndex;
        this.mCheated=mCheated;
    }
    public Pair(Parcel in){
        mIndex= in.readInt();
        mCheated=in.readByte()!=0;
    }
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags){
        out.writeInt(mIndex);
        out.writeByte((byte)(mCheated ? 1:0));
    }
    public final Parcelable.Creator<Pair> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Pair>(){
        public Pair createFromParcel(Parcel in){
            return new Pair(in);
        }
        public Pair[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Pair[size];
        }
    };
    public int getIndex(){
        return mIndex;
    }
    public boolean didCheat(){
        return mCheated;
    }
    public void setBoolean(boolean mCheated) {
        this.mCheated = mCheated;
    }
}
```

The code I am trying to use to attach the array of Pair objects to the bundle is as follows:

```
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArray(QUESTIONS_CHEATED, mCheatedResults);
}
```

I found documentation that indicated that this would work, but it does not seem to be working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you facing compilation error, run time exception or the values are not being saved? What is the exact issue?

Comment: There are no errors at run time or compilation.  However the app is not behaving as though the values have been saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading Parcelable arrays directly from the bundle will not work. Example:

```
Pair[] pairs = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray(QUESTIONS_CHEATED);
```

So this is how I read Parcelable arrays:

```
Parcelable[] parcelables = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray(QUESTIONS_CHEATED);
Pair[] pairs = new Pair[parcelables.length];
for(int i = 0; i < parcelables.length; i++) {
    pairs[i] = (Pair) parcelable[i];
}
```

If someone knows a better way, I would like to know please.